How do I create a new column in my DF of daily measurements that gives me the increase between today's and yesterday's measurement?
I have a column of datapoints for daily measurements in my DF. I would like to add a new column to said DF that tells me the increase or decrease of this measurement in comparison to yesterday's.
Basically by how much the measurement increased since yesterday.
I have:
# A tibble: 6 × 1
  measurement
       <dbl>
1          1
2          2
3          3
4          5
5          7
6         10

And I want:
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  measurement increase
       <dbl>    <dbl>
1          1       NA
2          2        1
3          3        1
4          5        2
5          7        2
6         10        3

I would expect something like this to work:
DF2 <- DF |> mutate(increase = measurement - measurement[])

I do, however, not know what to put inside the [] in order to tell R to take the previous rows value.

Use diff()
mutate(df, increase = c(NA, diff(measurement)))

Output:
  measurement increase
        <dbl>    <dbl>
1           1       NA
2           2        1
3           3        1
4           5        2
5           7        2
6          10        3


The lag function allows you to get the next value in a vector
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  measurement = c(1,2,3,5,7,10)
)

df %>% 
  mutate(increase = measurement - lag(measurement))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>   measurement increase
#>         <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1           1       NA
#> 2           2        1
#> 3           3        1
#> 4           5        2
#> 5           7        2
#> 6          10        3

Created on 2024-07-14 with reprex v2.1.1
